# unable to pass a varible or useState to another function in reactive native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to read the qr code and pass the data to another fuction to read from db.

```
const [scannedCode, setScannedCode] = useState("");

const handleBarCodeScanned = async ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    setScannedCode(data);
    console.log("code scanned: ", data);
    getStore({ scannedData: scanned, scannedCode: data });
  };

const getStore = async ({ scannedData, scannedCode }) => {
    const storeRef = collection(db, 'stores');
    console.log("scanned Data: ", scannedData);
    console.log("scanned Code: ", scannedCode);
    let data;
    if (!scannedData || scannedData == null) {
      data = scannedData;
    }
    else {
      data = scannedCode;
    }
    console.log(data);
    const q = query(storeRef, where('storeCode', '==', data));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    const storeList = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        storeList.push(doc.data());
    });

    if (storeList.length > 0) {
        setStore(storeList);
        getStoreAndNavigate();
    } else {
        setErrorMessage('Please scan the code again.');
        console.log("Please scan again");
    }
  }
```

scan takes place in handleBarCodeScanned. inside this function,
console.log("code scanned: ", data);
prints data.

however, when it's passed to getStore, it shows null, whether i only put data as parameter, scannedData as parameter or both as parameter.

(when only data is passed instead of scannedCode inside handleBarCodeScanned and const getStore = async (data), it calls console.log 2 times, first one prints out data but second shows null)

how can i fix this so it can be passed??

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The "set state function" that comes from `useState()` is an ***asynchronous*** function.  When your code calls it, JavaScript puts its invocation onto the "asynch queue" to be run "at a later time" -- specifically after the current function being run (i.e. your React component being rendered) finishes its current rendering.

So this will NEVER show the updated value:

```js
setFoo(42);
console.log("foo is", foo); // output will be whatever `foo` was BEFORE calling `setFoo()`
```

The act of updating a state variable's value with use of the "set state function" will have React schedule that component to be rendered again *after the value is updated* (i.e. after the "set state function" runs).

It is in the subsequent rendering that the state variable will have the new value, and it is in that subsequent rendering that you would want to send the data to your database.

Which means that you likely need to *protect your database code* so that it only runs under certain circumstances, such as your state variable having a new value.  The tool to handle this situation in React is `useEffect()`.